# Calling C DLL from C# caused Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm trying to use `zabbix_sender` function in my `c#` program. Here is my `c#` code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct zabbix_sender_value_t
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public String host;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public String key;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public String value;
}

[DllImport("zabbix_sender.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
public static extern int zabbix_sender_send_values(
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String address,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] ushort port, 
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String source, 
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] zabbix_sender_value_t values,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int count,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String result
);

static void Main()
{
    zabbix_sender_value_t values;
    values.host = "some_hostname";
    values.key = "agent.version";
    values.value = "2.0.0";
    string res = "";
    zabbix_sender_send_values("172.16.1.1", 10051, "127.0.0.1", values, 1, res);
}
```

This is definition of C function, i'm trying to call from DLL:

```
int zabbix_sender_send_values(
    const char *address, 
    unsigned short port,
    const char *source, 
    const zabbix_sender_value_t *values, 
    int count,
    char **result);

typedef struct
{
    char    *host;
    char    *key;
    char    *value;
}
zabbix_sender_value_t;
```

Execution of my C# code ends with exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

I played a lot with Marshalling parameters but no luck.

It is a first time i'm facing of use native `DLL` code by `c#` program, and i really don't know what do i have to do now.

Please any help, oppinion, kick to direction where to find out clue?

Thanks

Comment: The most obvious mistake is the *values* argument, you have to declare it as *ref* to get a zabbix_sender_value_t*.  Much more troublesome is the *result* argument, you certainly can't declare it as *string* since strings are immutable.  char** is ambiguous.  Could be an array of strings, most likely interpretation is `out IntPtr`.  Converted with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  With the very significant hangup that you don't know how to release the string buffer so you are liable to leak memory every time you call it.  This is not an interop-friendly function, use C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Just an off-the-cuff guess but did you enable "allow unsafe code" in your project properties and trying wrapping the call in an unsafe { } clause?

Answer (score 0):

the function accepts `char**` for result (the last) argument, while you are sending a ByVal string as this argument. string object wwill marshal as `char*` so you should declare it as `ref IntPtr` or `out string` (recommended for this case) to send a pointer of string to function.
But the main problem is because you are sending a `ByVal zabbix_sender_value_t` as `values` argument, while the function accepts an array of this structure. You can either declare it as an array or as a `ref` parameter if you want to sent just one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all Your sugestions.

I tried this

```
[DllImport("zabbix_sender.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
public static extern int zabbix_sender_send_values(
     [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String address,
     [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] ushort port, 
     [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String source, 
     ref zabbix_sender_value_t values,
     [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int count,
     out IntPtr result
);
```

and call function like this:

```
zabbix_sender_send_values("10.0.236.1", 10051, "10.0.236.12", ref values, 1, out res);
string output = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(res);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

It works, but if i try run in debug mode, the Exception PInvokeStackImbalance is thrown. It is not appropriate to use in production, isn't it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, thank You again. I finish with this code without any exception even in Debug mode. The problem with exception appeared only when i try build program in x86 platform. When i use x64 or AnyCPU ( 64 bit DLL ), everything works well. Maybe  misconfiguration?

Here is my final code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct zabbix_sender_value_t
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string host;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string key;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string value;
}

[DllImport("zabbix_sender.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
public static extern int zabbix_sender_send_values(
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string address,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int port, 
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string source, 
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref zabbix_sender_value_t values,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int count,
    out IntPtr result
);

static void Main()
{
    zabbix_sender_value_t values;
    values.host = "some_hostname";
    values.key = "zbx.trap";
    values.value = "99";
    IntPtr res ;
    unsafe {
        try
        {
            zabbix_sender_send_values("10.0.236.1", 10051, "10.0.236.12", ref values, 1, out res);
            string output = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(res);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```